# load data to Redshift & Bigquery directly from Hadoop/HDFS (local/on premises cluster)

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, google-bigquery, google-cloud-sql, amazon-redshift

Is there any way to load data to Redshift & Bigquery directly from Hadoop/HDFS (local/on premises cluster). I need to load 1TB of data to Redshift & Bigquery. So looking for efficient way to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load directly from Amazon EMR but if you're using a *local* Hadoop cluster then you'd have to export your data to S3 and use the COPY command to load into Redshift from there:

[Using a COPY command to load data](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_Loading_tables_with_the_COPY_command.html)

Comment: any clue on Bigquery ?

Comment: Afraid I don't have any experience with Bigquery, sorry.

Comment: Similar answer: Export your data as CSV or JSON to Google Cloud Storage, and load from there. Otherwise stream the data into BigQuery, but since it's 1 TB of already existing data, I would prefer going through GCS.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use an ETL tool that supports Hadoop, Redshift, BigQuery, Google Cloud Storage and Amazon S3.

Talend for Big Data is one ETL solution that support all these different sources of data.